# Accessing command argument in a database migration file

Tags: laravel, database-migration

I would like to get my inputted command argument(s) in a database migration file. Is this possible without having to fetch the $_SERVER global and getting my inputted command argument(s) through the 'argv' key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a class in which I've added a static property. 
Created a getter & setter for it and now I can simply call the getter from a random class.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables by defining the variable name before the command, e.g.

```
DB_NAME="database_name" php bin/console {command}
```

Comment: I'm not following .. How would I be able to fetch my command argument in a Laravel migration file?

Comment: You could then get the argument using `getenv('DB_NAME');`